# Not enough space to upgrade Mac OS via bootable USB

Tags: install, big-sur, bootable-disk

I'm trying to upgrade an oldish MacBook AIR from (I *think*) High Sierra to Big Sur.

I've made a bootable USB and it's working fine:

- Power ON with holding Option/Alt
- Select USB boot
- Goto Menu
- Install BigSur

It lists 2x HD's

- Macintosh HD
- Macintosh HD - Data

when I try and install this OS onto either, it says I need 9GB free space.

I have no idea how I can free any space on this (either?) partitions because I can't log into the machine. If I let it try and boot up *normally* it hangs in some "install?" screen with "29 minutes remaining" and hangs there for ever (i've had it on for over 24 hours).

So -> I'm hoping there might be some place I can use `Terminal` to manually `rm` some files, like the user's recycle bin or downloads or something?

I can't seem to see *any* real files when I use `Terminal` from the `INSTALL Menu` :( It's like .. everything is locked down/hidden?

I did fine ONE link to help me which suggested I remove the `VM` (virtual mem) disk, so I did that which released 2GB and now it's down to 7GB needed.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help, please?

Maybe I need *another* boot disk which can access the HD with some nice UI (like some ASCII GUI like the old days) ?

EDIT:

- Added pics
- Apologies for the blurry 2nd pic

EDIT2: I need to keep the data on the disks so I can grab it / back them up. So i cannot Erase the partition(s) with Disk Util.

Comment: More recent than High Sierra - HS would only have Macintosh HD.

Comment: interesting! is it worth trying another OS? Not sure how I can confirm the -age/model- of this MacBook Air, if i can't log into it.

Comment: Use time machine to back up your data. The delete

Comment: I don't have Time Machine setup? Or do you mean - set up TimeMachine -now- and do the backup? is that even possible, if i cannot log into the machine?

Comment: In Recovery, use Terminal and resetpassword command. https://osxdaily.com/2021/05/11/how-reset-macos-password-terminal/  If that fails you will need to erase everything and install a fresh copy of macOS (and lose any data on the system).

Comment: OR: Using your bootable USB, install macOS to large enough (64GB) thumb drive (better a real SSD). Running that you will be able to see the internal disk (assuming not encrypted) and do a backup.  Then wipe internal disk, install macOS and recover from backup.

Comment: Interesting - so i tried the `resetpassword` but that failed saying: there are no users on this volume. Looks like i'll need to try the 'install macOS to another USB disk`